# Stop main dblclick event from firing so that only child dbclick fires

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div called mydiv that serves as the container for my page... when someone double clicks, I do some stuff.

```
$('#mydiv').dblclick(function(e) {  

 // some stuff (**A**)
}
```

within that mydiv, I create jsplumb elements (which are just divs in themselves)

And when I double click on one of those, like this:

```
jsPlumb.bind("dblclick", function(e) { 
// some other stuff (**B**)
}
```

but the popup for both the **A** and **B** appear.

I'd like to prevent the popup in **A** from happening if **B** is dblclicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
jsPlub.bind("dblclick", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do the rest of your stuff
});
```

This will prevent the event from getting bubbled up.

Comment: Tried that, but it does the opposite... it blocks the rest of the code in jsplumb.bind from firing, but it fires the popup dialog from the $('#mydiv').dblclick

Comment: Must be something else wrong - check out the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wwunw9o1/).

Comment: Yeah, I see your thing working... only difference is that I have: 
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(e) { rather than $(".jsPlub").bind("dblclick", function(e) { because jsPlumb is a library (https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/parameters.html)

Comment: In that case, I've got no idea. I didn't realize that you had another library in there - hadn't heard of that library, and I figured jsPlumb was just your variable name for a jQuery selector.

Comment: Still, it's a valid answer.  The way I got around it was to var theTarget = e.target; if (theTarget.id !== 'mydiv') { return false; }... that solved it, and it was thanks to your suggestion.